# Why doesn't fgets read whole line in while loop but works in for loop?

Tags: c, linux, fgets

If my fgets is in a while loop, it only returns half the string. If it's in a for loop, it returns the whole string.. Any idea why?

Code below:

```
    FILE *fp; // File pointer
    char filename[] = "results.tsv";
    fp = fopen(filename, "r"); // Open file argv[1] for READ


    char s[4096];

    int num = atoi(fgets(s, sizeof(s), fp)); // Get first line (number of units in file)

    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < num; i++)
    {
        printf("%s", fgets(s, sizeof(s), fp)); // Prints everything
    }


    while (fgets(s, sizeof(s), fp) != NULL) // Loop until no more lines
    {
        printf("%s\n", s); // Only prints the x's
    }

    fclose(fp); // Close file
```

And the files contents:

```
1
xxxxxxxx       yyyy       eee
```

Where the big spaces are tabs (\t).

If I run it, I get:

For loop only:

```
xxxxxxxx       yyyy       eee
```

While loop only:

```
xxxxxxxx
```

Thanks.

Comment: Did you try removing the `for` and using only the `while`? Because I don't see resetting of the position in the file after the `for`.

Comment: Just so it won't be any misunderstandings. You have tried once with the `for` loop but not the `while` loop, and a second time with the `while` loop but not the `for` loop? In other words, your real code doesn't look like it does in the question, i.e. you really don't have both loops after each other?

Comment: I only put them both in here to show you the two codes. In my code I have only one of them.

Comment: I compile your code with only while loop, it prints `xxxxxxxx       yyyy       eee` though

Comment: Works For Me (TM). Please post code that reproduces your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already diagnosed, your code 'works for me'.  Here's the SSCCE I created for it.  If invoked with no arguments, it uses the `while` loop.  If invoked with any arguments, it uses the `for` loop.  Either way, it works correctly for me.  Note that the code doesn't use the return value from `fgets()` directly; it checks that the input operation succeeded before doing so.  It also echos what it is doing and reading as it goes.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    FILE *fp;
    char filename[] = "results.tsv";

    if ((fp = fopen(filename, "r")) == 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s: failed to open file %s\n", argv[0], filename);
        exit(1);
    }

    char s[4096];

    if (fgets(s, sizeof(s), fp) == 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Premature EOF\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    int num = atoi(s);
    printf("Num lines: %d\n", num);

    if (argc > 1)
    {
        printf("For loop:\n");
        for (int i = 0; i < num; i++)
        {
            if (fgets(s, sizeof(s), fp) == 0)
            {
                fprintf(stderr, "Premature EOF\n");
                exit(1);
            }
            printf("%d: %s", i+1, s);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        int i = 0;
        while (fgets(s, sizeof(s), fp) != NULL)
        {
            printf("While loop:\n");
            printf("%d: %s", ++i, s);
        }
    }

    fclose(fp);

    return 0;
}
```

If you use this code and it fails on your system, then you could submit your evidence.  Amongst other things, you should identify the platform on which you're working, and you should give a hex dump (or equivalent) of the data in the file `results.tsv`.  The data file I used, for example, contained the bytes:

```
0x0000: 31 0A 78 78 78 78 78 78 78 78 09 79 79 79 79 09   1.xxxxxxxx.yyyy.
0x0010: 65 65 65 65 0A                                    eeee.
0x0015:
```

Answer (score 1):

Before start reading with while loop, you have to make the position of reading from the stream(file) start at the same position where the for loop start reading

You can do it with one of the 2 ways:

1) close the file and reopen it and read the first line before starting the while loop

2) Use the fseek (as **KiriliKirov** said) to point  at the same position where the for loop start reading. To do you have get the current position (position where the for loop start reading) with the `ftell()` function:

```
int num = atoi(fgets(s, sizeof(s), fp));
long int start_read = ftell (fp); // get the current postion //add this line in your code

.....

fseek ( fp , start_read , SEEK_SET ); // add this line in your code
while (fgets(s, sizeof(s), fp) != NULL)
```

The second solution will avoid the close and the reopen the file and the read of the first line.

[`ftell()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/ftell/) returns the current value of the position indicator of the stream.

[`fseek()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fseek/) Sets the position indicator associated with the stream to a new position

Comment: because the fgets make the file pointer pointing at the end of the last readed charachter. In this cas the for loop make make the position of the file pointer at the end of the file.

Comment: Well, `fseek` could be used, instead of closing and opening the file again.